# dynamic json with array

Tags: jquery, json, yii

Im using YII and it sends the data as "table[attr1]=1&table[attr2]=2&table[attr3]=3" so to make a request using jquery I use:

```
 $.ajax({  
        url:"url",
        data:{
             'table[attr1]':1,
             'table[attr2]':2,
             'table[attr3]':3,
        },
        success:function(resp){
            //ok
        }
    });
```

but I need to make this data json dynamicaly, I tryed this but dosent work:

```
$("input").each(function(){ //build the data json       
    form.table[this.name]=this.value;  //the name is 'attr1' , the value is 1
});  



     $.ajax({  
        url:"url",
        data:form, //send the JSON here
        success:function(resp){
            //ok
        }
    });
```

This will send the data empty

Any ideas how to build this json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var form = {}; // create object
$('input').each(function(){
    form[this.name] = this.value; // add name/value
});
```

then form will hold an object like depending on name/value and assuming your element names are `table[attr1]` etc

```
{
  'table[attr1]': 1,
  'table[attr2]': 2,
  'table[attr3]': 3,
}
```

Comment: Thank you wirey, I didnt use this approach because I thought will turn the json into a useless array

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSON involved here what you are sending is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, for your code to work you have to create the table property of the form object first.

```
var form = {table:{}};
$("input").each(function(){  
    form.table[this.name] = this.value;  //the name is 'attr1' , the value is 1
});
$.ajax({  
    url:"url",
    data:form, 
    success:function(resp){
        //ok
    }
});
```